# wall-clock profiler for Linux

Tags: linux, profiling

I'm looking for a simple [wall-clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elapsed_real_time) profiler for Linux. I just want to see the list of symbols/methods, the count of calls to that method, and the average time spent in that method per call to it in microseconds. I tried the built-in perf tools; they seem to report active CPU time only. I'm also open to suggestions for how to write a tool on Linux that knows when methods are called & returned in some other process (using the perf API or whatever).

Comment: Please clarify what `strace` appears to lack.

Comment: The `strace` summary seems to be close to what I want; I just need the top 5 stack traces for each of the top 5 slow system calls in the summary.

Answer (score 2):

After wasting a whole day researching this and testing various tools (after an entire career of depending on gprof, which never really worked), I realized that such a tool just doesn't exist.  There are lots of nice tools (like perf, gperftools, etc.), but none of them give you a true wall-clock sample of where your program is really spending its time, including time that it spends waiting on I/O.  Valgrind callgrind is the only one that can do it, but the overhead (50x slowdown) is unacceptable in a production environment.

So I wrote my own, and it actually works.  The only dependency is GDB, which you probably have already if you're doing this stuff.

https://github.com/jasonrohrer/wallClockProfiler

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I will try it in the near future.

Comment: I'm still working on it, but I think it's pretty close to done.... spent a lot of time improving it yesterday through use in a production environment.  GDB/MI (the interface that it uses to control GDB) is a little flaky, and I also got bitten by SIGPIPE (which my target program was ignoring for networking reasons, but GDB was still catching).  But now it can attach to a live running server process (my game server, which currently has 100+ players connected to it at the same time), grab samples for however many seconds, and then detach without disturbing the server process at all.  Good stuff.

Comment: I tried it out and worked great for me, very useful.

Comment: Following up: I did try this some time ago. However, as it did not support multiple threads, it did not work for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with Google's CPU Profiler. A link, along with instructions is on the github: https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools.

To make it use walltime, set `CPUPROFILE_REALTIME=1` (Warning, this will break sleeps)

Comment: Breaking sleeps sounds pretty severe. I'm certain my application uses a number of those as well as various timers. Part of the point of this was to see if I was hitting any of those inadvertently.